# CSS Selector for first matching element

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<section class="section-one"></section>
<section class="section-two"></section>
<nav></nav>
<section class="section-three"></section>
<section class="section-four"></section>
```

Because section order is coming from a CMS, section order is unknown (i.e., `section-two` and `section-three` could be swapped). I want to select the first sibling section after `section-two` but can't use adjacent sibling selectors as there are potentially other elements between sections.

How can I select the first section following `section-two` considering there could be one or multiple elements between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.section-two ~ section {
  /* Set styles */
}
.section-two ~ section ~ section {
  /* Undo styles */
}
```

```css
.section-two ~ section {
  background: #0f0;
}
.section-two ~ section ~ section {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-one">One</section>
<section class="section-two">Two</section>
<nav>Nav</nav>
<section class="section-three">Three</section>
<section class="section-four">Four</section>
```

Comment: For a purely CSS solution (which is what I would prefer in this case rather than pulling in JS), this seems like the least brittle way to resolve the lack of a next of type CSS selector. Should work well. Thanks Oriol!

Answer (score 0):

you could use `[class^="section-"]` so select any class that begins with ".section-" and I used `nth-last-of-type(2)` to count back 2 from the end and select the right element but without `nth-last-of-type(2)` you get every .section-NUMBER after .section-two

```css
section {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: gray;  
}
nav {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: gray;
}
.section-two ~ [class^="section-"]:nth-last-of-type(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-one"></section>
<section class="section-two"></section>
<nav></nav>
<section class="section-three"></section>
<section class="section-four"></section>
```

Comment: Thanks @darham but you're selecting the `nav` tag.  How do you select the first `section` tag after `section-two` considering the order of `section-two` and `section-three` could be swapped?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery 
$( ".section-two ~ section" ).css(/* do whatever*/);

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can achieve this just with css-selectors, they are a bit limited in terms of traversing the dom.

As an example you could use jQuery traversing to do:

```
$('.section-two').nextAll('section').first()
```

This will select the first section after `.section-two`, check this

Hope it helps.
Cheers!

**EDIT:** Ok, it seems you can select distance sibling by setting the style and then undoing it, as suggested by @Oriol. I'll keep this answer as a reference for how to solve it using jquery, for future reference.

```js
$('.section-two').nextAll('section').first().css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="section-one">1</section>
<section class="section-two">2</section>
<nav></nav>
<section class="section-three">3</section>
<section class="section-four">4</section>
```